# ASP.NET MVC runtime installation requirement in "test" server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, and i have deployed it locally in my box. Now if i want to deploy it in a "Test" server (which is a tightly controlled environment), what do i need to install in the test server at the minimum - i.e. on top of the pre-installed ASP.NET 2.0 and .NET framework.

Do i need to isntall ASP.NET MVC runtime - obviously i won't be allowed to install any VS.NET or developer specific MVC stuff. It has to be the minimum runtime that is required to run the MVC ASP.NET app and nothing more.

Where do i get such an installer? Somewhere in MS web site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond having the latest version of the .NET framework ([3.5 sp1](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/6/1/061F001C-8752-4600-A198-53214C69B51F/dotnetfx35setup.exe)), the only thing you may have to do is tweak your IIS settings depending on the version you are running.

You can read this great blog [entry](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx) from Phil Haack on it as well talking about what needs to be in the BIN.

Here is a great [writeup](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNETMVC/216_Hosting_and_Deployment_of_an_ASPNET_MVC_Application_in_IIS6_and_IIS7.aspx) on what is required.

Answer (score 1):

During the Beta, Scott Hanslemann wrote up the details on deploying an ASP.NET MVC application to a .NET 2.0 server:

> [Deploying ASP.NET MVC on ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingASPNETMVCOnASPNET20.aspx)

That will do the job if you can't get the server updated to .NET 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is a BIN deployment.  A BIN deployment allows you to copy the required DLLs to the BIN directory on the target server, allowing them to run in a Medium Trust environment.  No installation required.

For instructions on how to do this, see:

**Bin Deploying ASP.NET MVC**
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx

Answer (score -1):

http://www.asp.net/mvc/download/

or, more directly:  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en

Comment: You shouldn't need to install MVC dev tools on deployment machine.

Comment: Hi Joel - I thought the above download was for development, and so i should not be using it for test server deployment?

Comment: But i will need to install something on the deployment m/c so that the MVC functionality can work, otherwise how would it work with just the sandard ASP.NET framework/runtime?